# Why does this JavaScript not correctly update input values?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have two input fields, and without changing their names (i.e., I have to use the name with the brackets), how do I make this javascript code work?

```
<script>

    function calc_concreteprice(mainform) {
        var oprice;
        var ototal;

        oprice = (eval(mainform.['concrete[concrete][sqft]'].value) * eval(mainform.['concrete[concrete][price]'].value));
        ototal = (oprice);

        mainform.'concrete[concrete][quick_total]'.value = ototal;
    }   

</script>
```

Here's the HTML of the input area.

```
<tr>
                        <td>Concrete Base Price</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="concrete[concrete][price]" value="" class="item_mult" onBlur="calc_concreteprice(document.forms.mainform);" /> per SF <strong>times</strong> <input type="text" name="concrete[concrete][sqft]" value="" class="item_mult" onBlur="calc_concreteprice(document.forms.mainform);" /> SF</td>
                        <td> = <input type="text" name="concrete[concrete][quick_total]" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
```

I know I can get it working by changing_the_input_name_with_underscores but I need to have the names with the brackets (storing the form contents in an array).

**EDIT:** Left this question as a community wiki, so please contribute as you see fit to code changes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
mainform['estimate[concrete][sqft]'].value
```

and so on?

Also: you seem to be using `eval()` to turn a string into a numerical value. It is pretty much always a bad idea to use `eval()` on raw user input. I would advise using `parseInt()` and/or `parseFloat()` instead.

Comment: I'll make changes out of eval(). Putting brackets around the name like that doesn't work, though.

Comment: Yup yup - and right you are! I am ever thankful for the returning support of the stackoverflow community. Thank you for your answer!